# HTML preloader delay (Elementor)

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, elementor

I need some help. So there is this page that is using an iframe, for that reason the Cumulative Layout shift is pretty noticeable. So we wanted to use a preloader so that you cant see that. But the preloader code only shows the preloader for like 100ms. I wanted to change this is so I added this code in between the script tag. But now the preloader isn't going away at all. Just spinning on forever

This is the code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() {});
    }, 200); // set the time here
  });
});
```

```css
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url('https://example.com/example.svg') 50% 50% no-repeat #aa9767;
  /* Change the #fff here to your background color of choice for the preloader fullscreen section */
}

.elementor-editor-active .loader {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<div class="loader"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things seems wrong:

1. Your selector seems wrong, I am assuming its meant to be `.loader`
2. The function parameter in `document.ready` doesn't take parameters

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     $(window).load(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
       $('.loader').fadeOut('slow');
      }, 200); // set the time here
    });
   });
   ```